# How to Join All the Trees Together?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scripting, uv, node-editor

[image: trees][image: nodes][image: the mesh not corresponds]My object consist of many trees. So if I "bake" any of the tree at the end I have many pieces and I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them. Is there a way to join all the trees together into one big tree and to get a united polygonal shape?

Comment: Hi, you are using a [tag:nodes] tag, is your question about [tag:animation-nodes], [tag:sverchok], or geometry nodes? Please [edit] your question and make this more clear. Some images would be useful as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Please add screenshots of your interface and more information

Comment: i added the photo)

Comment: You need to add more information. I don't see any tree on your picture

Answer (score 0):

I see solution in using viewer bmesh and than operate in separate tree by object in and joining them

https://yadi.sk/d/Y0755AytIfALnQ

try this file as example
[image]